# TextinputEdittext and TextInputLayout on focus out should return the hint to the first state

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble using TextInputLayout and TextinputEdittext. As you see I am creating a custom RelativeLayout wherein inside is the said layouts.

When running it shows the correct behavior
[image]
Now I added a code on 'onfocuschange' of TextinputEdittext, if it is not onfocused it should show an error but if the field is empty the hint should return to the previous state.

```
 @Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    isFocused = hasFocus;

    if (hasFocus) {
         //some code
    }
    else{
        mTextInputLayout.setError(//error text)
        mTextInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.HintErrorStyle);
        mTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        //other codes
    }

    mTextInputLayout.setHintEnabled(true);
    mTextInputLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
}
```

This is where my problem starts. What I am getting is:
 [image]

Where what I should be expecting is, the hint should return to the starting state since there is no text on the TextinputEdittext.

Is this the default of android or am I missing something?

PS

English is not my native language so pardon me for some grammar issues

Thanks

Comment: It's the default behavior of android. If you get an error message and you shift the focus  the hint remains at top :).

Comment: I think setting error to null should fix this problem. Can you try and reply back

Comment: @GaneshKalal I tried doing that. The hint will return to previous state but the error message is gone. What I am trying to do is retain the errors but the hint should return to the edittext as there is no input.

Comment: @Umair so the default behavior of android is when we initiate to show the error, the hint will always goes up unless we force the to disable error or setError(null)? so I need a custom TextInputLayout in case I want to accomplish this? Im trying to check the documentation for this so that I can defend this 'but still no luck. Thanks by the way for the quick response

Comment: @Androyds yup that's the default behavior. and yup you need to make a custom TextInputLayout :).

Answer (score 0):

When isFocused = false at that time you should setfocus with another view so your hint is look as your previous state.