# How do I revert TextEditInputLayout to have the hints where they originally are?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have multiple TextEditInputLayouts on the sign up page (fragment) and when I first open it up everything is fine. However when I use the clear function below it some of the hints end up at the top and some end up on the line. I would ideally want the view to look as it did originally and I don't understand why half of the views have the hints at the top and the other half have the hints on the line when I call the same clear function on all the field and all the xml elements are exactly the same (other than id/hint string/etc).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it or at least how to fix it after it has happened?

**Related XML**

```html
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/id_1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="@string/lbl_x"
                            android:theme="@style/themeX"
                            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorTheme">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/input_1"
                                style="@style/editTextTheme"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                                android:maxLines="1" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try `editText.setText("")` instead of `null`? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694778/textinputedittext-and-textinputlayout-on-focus-out-should-return-the-hint-to-the) might be helpful

Comment: You can user recreate to bring your activity and widgets to default its like onCreate just faster.So try calling recreate() in your click event.Its not elegant in pre lollipop though

Answer (score 0):

Using editText.setText("") instead of null worked.